# Accessing variable in outer scope?

Tags: javascript, closures, scope

```
(function () {
    var x = 1;
    return {
        f: function (x) {
            alert(x);
        }
    };
}()).f(2);
```

Suppose I don't want to rename either variable. There is no way to, from within `f`, access the variable `x`, which was declared first - right?

Comment: you could expose the variable with a method

Comment: Why don't you want to rename either variable?

Comment: The parameter `x` *shadows* the variable `x`. Like in a lot of other programming languages (which sometimes can be resolved but in this example, no).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Correct. Because you have a different `x` in `function (x)`, any attempt to access `x` will get that one (the nearest scope). It blocks access to any `x` in a wider scope.

Answer (score 5):

This allows you to use both x (1) and x (2) at the same time.

```
(function () {
    var x = 1;
    return {
        f: function (x) {
            alert(x); // paramter (=2)
            alert(this.x); // scoped variable (=1)
        },
        x:x
    };
}()).f(2);
```

Comment: An interesting approach. Thanks! Though, in the real-life case, I do not want to expose that `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You could return the variable with the function:

```
(function () {
    var x = 1;
    return {
        f: function () {
            alert(this.x);
        },
        x:x
    };
}()).f();
```

Answer (score 1):

> There is no way to, from within `f`, access the variable `x`, which was declared first

No, there is not. The inner scope `x` hides the outer scope `x`.

```
var closure = (function () {
    var local = {};
    local.x = 1;
    return {
        f: function (x) {
            alert(x || local.x);
        }
    };
}());

closure.f(2);  // alerts "2"
closure.f();   // alerts "1"
```

You can't have an inner variable called "local", of course. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Aware of implicit async calls which make you think that you can't access of variable from outer scope:

```
result = {}
jQuery.ajax({ // it is a async call!
    url: "/some/url",
    success: function(data) {
        result = JSON.parse(data);
    }
});

return result; // Result will be still {} because function returns before request has done.
```